# How can I get access to a map from another class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, fluttermap

I have a map <String, dynamic> in class called `show_page.dart`, it takes it's values from functions in the same class.

```
Map<String, dynamic> records = {};
```

What I want is to use it in another class page called `records_page.dart` to put it in ListView.builder which it will put (keys, values) in cards for each index.

This is a simple of my map keys & values.

```
I/flutter ( 8165): {qq: 00:00:06.24, uu: 00:00:10.04}
```

So, How can I get access to it?

Here an image shows the `records_page.dart` with a fake example just to catch the idea.

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LumD7.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to "share" datas from a widget to another.
The easiest solution for you would probably be to pass the `Map<String, dynamic> records = {};` as a parameter of your `RecordsPage` widget.

```
class RecordsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> records;
  
  const RecordsPage(this.records);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

And in your `ShowPage` widget you can instantiate your `RecordsPage` with the following implementation

```
class ShowPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> records = {"qq" : "00:00:06.24"};

    return RecordsPage(records);
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't make since

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you meant here